# Unable to get json node values

Tags: json, rest, rest-assured, web-api-testing, rest-assured-jsonpath

This is the json response format that I have and need to read the first node value "html". I have tried to few ways to get the value but unable to get it

```
[
   {
      "html": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n                                                <html>\n                                                    <head>\n                                                        <\/html>\n                                                \n",
<\/html>\n                                                \n",
      "headers": {},
      "subject": "Register new account",
      "messageId": "475603953.247.1565607800153@dfrsbdd201.abc.com.au",
      "priority": "normal",
      "from": [],
      "to": [],
      "date": "2019-08-12T11:03:20.000Z",
      "receivedDate": "2019-08-12T11:09:42.000Z",
      "receivedAt": "2019-08-12T11:09:44.900Z"
   },
   {+},
   {+}
]
```

I tried couple of things

```
    RequestSpecification emailReq = given().with().pathParam("email",emailName);
        Response emailResp = emailReq.contentType("application/json").get("https://restmail.net/mail/{email}");

JSONObject value = new JSONObject(emailResp.asString());
```

I got this error

```
org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:505)
```

and then I removed this last line to use But this does not gives me error. pls refer screenshot for this

```
JSONArray responseJson = new JSONArray(emailResp.asString());
```

Tried this as well

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> jsonObjectsInArray = emailResp.jsonPath().getList("$");
for (HashMap<String, Object> singleLeg : jsonObjectsInArray) {
    String value = (String) singleLeg.get("html");

}
```

But again array size is 0

Need some suggestion of how to get the value of node - "html". Pls suggest. what mistake am I doing here?

Thanks in advance

[image: for the second way]

Comment: Hi, the shared data is invalid JSON, is it exactly what is returned by the API? Thanks for editing the question to quote the error messages returned together with the lines of code causing the error.

Comment: @Mehdi thanks for your reply.  I have edited the post with some more info as you had asked for. Json response is the format as I have mentioned in the question. pls advise.

Comment: Here is the answer

RequestSpecification emailReq = given().with().pathParam("email",emailName);
        int retries = 5;
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> emails = Arrays.asList();
.
.
. emailResp = emailReq.get("https://restmail.net/mail/{email}");
            if (emailResp.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                emails = emailResp.jsonPath().getList("$");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RequestSpecification emailReq = given().with().pathParam("email",emailName); 
int retries = 5; 
List<HashMap<String, Object>> emails = Arrays.asList(); 
. . . 
emailResp = emailReq.get("restmail.net/mail{email}"); 
if (emailResp.getStatusCode() == 200) { emails = emailResp.jsonPath().getList("$");
String email = emails.get(0).get("html").toString();
```